# Database frontend for multiple db engines

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, frontend

**I'm looking for a database frontend which should have the following features**

1. can access PostgreSQL and MySQL databases
2. can handle schemata
3. offers a nice sql query tool
4. supports an import and export functionality (something like tab separated text files)
5. it's free
6. *looks awesome - every time when a colleague comes to my office he must
   get the feeling: oh boy, this man really knows his job and should get more money!*

At the moment I've used phpmyadmin, phppgadmin, pgadminIII, mysqladmin and dbVisualizer. Furthermore I was a big fan of the aqua datastudio until it became commercial. This tools offers a great variety of functionalities which can simplify a programmer's life. However, now you have to buy a license...I'm a scientist and money for software is limited. =)

Answer (score 7):

My Swiss army knife for databases is [SquirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/).

- universal client (JDBC based)
- extensible (through [plugins](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=plugins))
- does the job

It's UI is not its biggest strength though. But I rate higher what I can do with it than the way it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenOffice Base](http://www.openoffice.org/product/base.html) can use ODBC to connect to almost anything, including PostgreSQL and MySQL.

Point 6 might be a problem... :(

Comment: Bounty awarded because Base does provide a lot more in the customisable UI department.